# Content written in the Page edit box not showing in the published page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am not sure what I am missing. Please guide me and I apologize if my knowledge is too less.

I have a home template file i.e. template-home.php which actually contains nothing for now and is only containing the following lines ->

```
<?php
 /**
  * This is the front page code
  * Template Name: HomePage
  */
 get_header();



 get_footer();
?>
```

I have created a page from wp admin and given the page title "Home" then I selected template "Homepage" for this page I have created from wp admin. Hence I have set the static front page to display "Home". Its perfectly showing the Home page as front page. But when I am giving any content in the edit box of the page "Home" from wp-admin and updating, those contents are not displaying in frontend. But if I put any content in the "Homepage" template , only then its getting displayed. I am giving an example what I tried below-

When I am giving the following in the page edit box then nothing is displayed in real.

```
[rev_slider_vc alias="homebanner" title="Home Slideshow"]
```

For your information the above is shortcode of revolution slider which is working perfectly , if I use it in any post. So the shortcode has no error for sure. Another thing whatever I write in the content box is actually not getting displayed in real.

Now the slider code, if I am putting directly into the Home template i.e. template-home.php then slider is getting displayed. The code is as follows ->

```
<?php
  /**
   * This is the front page code
   * Template Name: HomePage
   */
 get_header();

 // Revolution Slider
 putRevSlider('homebanner', 'homepage');

 get_footer();
?>
```

Though my purpose is getting served well by putting code into the template file directly. But I want that the content I put in the edit box of the page from wp admin can get displayed in real. So what I need to do for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/

You need a loop and you need `the_content` to grab the content from the text editor.

A very basic example:

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        //
        // Post Content here

                 the_content();

        //
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
```

Work with that first with some plain text to test the loop.

Then add your shortcode for the slider `[rev_slider_vc alias="homebanner" title="Home Slideshow"]` in the text editor. And, look at the docs for the slider on how to place the function `putRevSlider('homebanner', 'homepage');` directly in the page template file, if you want to do that rather than using the shortcode in the editor.

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development for how WordPress themes are structured and the types of basic files you need in each theme, i.e. index.php, style.css, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Now I need to dig deeper . Thanks again :)